# Django urls handle slug with slash inside e.g. /main/subpage

Tags: django

I have this in my `urls.py`

```
path('<str:slug>', views.page, name='page'),
```

which I want to handle any links that didn't get caught above, think of the slug like a url link that can be deep like `main\subpage\sub-sub-link` which I can match to a page.

Thing is it seems the slug will only handle one layer like `\main` is there a way to pipe all of that sublink info e.g. `domain.com/this/that/that-that` so my slug will be `this/that/that-that`

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like`path('<slug:post>/', views.page, name='page')`

But remember your page function should take post as slug parameter.

Like

```
def page(request, post):
  post = get_object_or_404(model_name, post)
```

And when using a tag for links you can use it like `href="{% url 'page' post.slug %}"`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `get_absolute_url()`

In your **models.py**

```
from django.urls import reverse

# some model...

class Post(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()

    # ...other model parameters

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('<your_app_name>:page', {'slug':self.slug})
```

In your **urls.py**

```
path('<slug>/', views.page, name='page'),
```

In your **views.py**

```
from .models import Post

def page(request):
  posts = Post.objects.all()

  context = {
       'posts':posts
   }
   return render('path_to_your_template.html', request, context)
```

In your **template.html**
You can do

```
{%for post in posts %}
    <a href={{post.get_absolute_url}}>{{post.title}}</a>
{%endfor%}
```